# Histogram without vertical separation lines and with custom contour width

Tags: python, plotly, histogram

I'm wondering how to obtain the following result in `plotly` for histograms, i.e. no vertical lines displayed and a custom line width for contour

[image]

the image is taken from the following [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2312.03687). It seems that the figures were indeed produced using `plotly`.

EDIT:

I have found out that in `matplotlib` it is pretty straightforward doing something similar, like illustrated in the following example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.rcParams['font.size'] = 10
plt.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 600
x = np.random.randn(400)
plt.hist(x, histtype='step', linewidth=5,color='green')
plt.hist(x, alpha=0.5, color='green')
```

but so far I haven't found an equivalent of `histtype='step'` in `plotly`.

Answer (score 2):

The histograms in plotly are different from the logic in matplotlib. See this for more [information](https://plotly.com/python/histograms/). There is a way to customize line widths in your intended step graph. Use the line mode of the scatter plot to specify the shape of that line. See this for a detailed [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47681016/python-how-to-create-a-step-plot-with-offline-plotly-for-a-pandas-dataframe) of lines. In addition, the fill color is specified in RBGA format with transparency. Then we change the theme of the graph to a simplified one to match the image in the question. Finally, the y-axis is cut off in the automatically drawn graph, so we specify the lower and upper limits of the y-axis and provide margins.

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(20240204)
x = np.random.randn(400)
hist, bins = np.histogram(x)

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[x for x in range(len(hist))],
                         y=hist, mode='lines',
                         line=dict(color='lightgreen', width=3, shape='hv'),
                         fill='tozerox',
                         fillcolor='rgba(144,238,144,0.5)' # lightgreen+alpha:0.5
                        )
             )

fig.update_layout(template='simple_white', yaxis_range=[min(hist), max(hist)+5])
fig.show()
```

[image]